# How to build a "decorator" function in TypeScript that can handle multiple types

Tags: typescript

My question stems from not knowing TypeScript fully (inherited project), so please bare with me:

I have a very repetitive code that looks something like this:

```
import {EventA, EventB, .... EventG} from './events'
import {EntityA, EntityB, ....EntityG} from './entities'

//all the event objects are defined: EventA extends Event
//all the entity objects are defined: EntityA extends Entity

export function handleEventA(event: eventA): void {
  let entity = new EntityA(event.id)
  entity.date = event.date
  entity.address = event.address
  ...
  entity.SomethingUniqueToEntityA = event.SomethingUniqueToEntityA
  entity.save()
}

...

export function handleEventG(event: eventG): void {
  let entity = new EntityG(event.id)
  entity.date = event.date
  entity.address = event.address
  ...
  entity.SomethingUniqueToEntityG = event.SomethingUniqueToEntityG
  entity.save()
}
```

As you can see, it's very repetitive: I always instantiate an entity corresponding to an event, and always copy the same 2-3 fields from the event to the entity, before proceeding to handle the unique entity fields.

What I thought I'd have is some sort of a decorator (or maybe a factory??) function, that will allow me to do something like:

```
function decorate(entity: Entity, event: Event): Entity {
  entity.date = event.date
  entity.address = event.address
  return entity
}

export function handleEventA(event: eventA): void {
  let entity = new EntityA(event.id)
  entity = decorate(entity, event)
  ...
  entity.SomethingUniqueToEntityA = event.SomethingUniqueToEntityA
  entity.save()
}
```

Or maybe even some factory function that will instantiate the entities.

I tried defining something like `decorate(entity: EntityA | EntityB |... EntityG, event: EventA | EventB |... EventG)` but it gets unwieldy and repetitive as well.

My problem is: how do I define the `decorate` function to allow all entities and events as parameters? Do I even need to return `entity` or is it called by reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way should be to define only signature you need for your `decorate` function. This is possible because of TypeScript's structural typing. It's enough that "shape" of type matches - so any `Event` (`EventA`, `EventB`), or `Entity` having those 2 properties can be passed in as input parameter.

```typescript
interface IDateAndAddress {
  date: Date,
  address: string
}

function decorate(entity: IDateAndAddress, event: IDateAndAddress): void {
  entity.date = event.date;
  entity.address = event.address;
}
```

You can be a bit more specific, to ensure that you can not swap `entity` and `event` by mistake, when calling the `decorate` function, but this is guts of the solution.

Comment: I'm not in control of either Entity or Event codes - they're generated. Also, the properties are not as top level properties, for example, to get the address, I need to do something like `entity.address = event.block.address`.

Comment: Then just shape `IDataAndAdress` the way you need it, including nested objects. Shape has to match to the properties you want to manipulate in the function, nothing more. It'll work.

Comment: I tried your solution: defined the interface and added a `export function decorate(a: IEntityFields, b: Event) : void {}` I get `TS2304: Cannot find name 'IEntityFields'`, with the line highlighting the `IEntityFields` - even though it's defined right above the fuction. Is that a result of the `export`?

Comment: It shouldn't be result of export. Hard to say what you're doing wrong. Typo maybe? There is a working sample [here](https://tsplay.dev/mZ874w), if it helps.

Comment: I appreciate the demo code. I'm not in control of the TS compiler here (code is generated by a library), but if I use commas in the `interface` instead of semicolon or leaving it empty, it complains about the types (TS003). So something is amiss.

Comment: Ok, seems like your idea works in a normal environment, so I'll mark it. Doesn't solve my problem - but that's life :(